# AttributeError: ​module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user // i have Django rest installed

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

**Error I am getting**

> AttributeError: module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'

**Signal I am trying to send when user logs in**

```
def auth_done(sender, **kwargs):
    print('User has logged in')
    tok = Token.objects.create(user=request.user)
    print(tok.key())


user_logged_in.connect(auth_done, sender=User)
```

**Login view**

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['first_name']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=name, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            print(user)
            login(request, user)
            tok = Token.objects.create(user=request.user)
            print(tok.key)
            print('User is authenticated')
        else:
            print('Not authenticated')
    return render(request, 'Auth/user.html')
```

**Settings**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.isAuthenticated'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function `auth_done` you are trying to access `request.user`, what exactly is `request` here? I assume you have an import like the below and try to use it as the request:

```
from django.http import request
```

The `request` here is not what you think it is, it is the *module* which contains the definition of request classes (`HttpRequest`, etc.). Instead you want the request from the *keyword arguments* passed to the signal or in fact you don't even want that, since the `user` is also passed as a keyword argument:

```
def auth_done(sender, **kwargs):
    print('User has logged in')
    # tok = Token.objects.create(user=kwargs['request'].user)
    tok = Token.objects.create(user=kwargs['user'])
    print(tok.key())


user_logged_in.connect(auth_done, sender=User)
```

Moving further it appears you are unnecessarily duplicating this code since your `login_in` is *also* doing the same thing after logging the user in.